# How to use makecab.exe to create cabinet (*.CAB) file using ALL FILES in a folder?

Tags: installshield, winapi

How to use [makecab.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583149%28v=office.11%29.aspx) to create cabinet (*.CAB) file using ALL FILES in a folder?

I have a large number of files and its very hard to add them in the .DDF file which is used by makecab utility. So I want to know how to specify in a DDF file that all files in a given folder should be added in my CAB.

I have extracted one CAB file from MSI created using InstallShield. I have replaced one of the files and now I want to create a new CAB archive.

Comment: for reference for people like me dying inside trying to figure out how to use makecab, here's a powershell script i just made: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411440/makecab-create-a-cab-file-from-all-the-files-in-a-folder/24668955#24668955

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by makecab.exe. You need to specify which files you want to include.

Either way, if you are trying to modify a MSI CAB, it won't work. The CAB is just a files container. The actual file information used during install is stored in the MSI database.

A better solution would be to import the MSI in a setup authoring tool, make the modifications you need and generate a new MSI.